# Can I disable Google Web Light for my website?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-website-optimizer

Google Web Light is designed to re-format pages to optimize them for mobile browsers.   When it does so with my site, it does a really awful job. Some part of my website are not working and it looks ugly too.

I want to disable Google Web Light for my website,. I don't want Google to render an improper or incorrect website to my customers.

Example:

[image]

There are lots of difference between my original website & Google optimized  lite content.

Comment: I think, most of the people are having the same issues, without a Google solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Google help document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en) describes how to have your site opt-out of Google Web Light:

> If you do not want your pages to be transcoded, set the HTTP header `Cache-Control: no-transform` in your page response. If Googlebot sees this header, your page will not be transcoded.
>
> Please note that pages that opt-out of being transcoded will be labeled in search results to indicate to users that they may take longer to load and may use more data.

It also has a way that you can send feedback about how your site looks using it:

> Please send feedback to googleweblight@google.com. If you see issues with a particular page, please include the URL.

Comment: where put this code? i have WordPress website to avoid googleweblight

Comment: `Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"` into your *.htaccess* file

Comment: Thanks, But my website loads faster, I don't why Google things the other way.